# Display content to the right of a table

Tags: html, css

I am trying to develop a web page that has a table running down the left hand side of a div and then displays content on the right. I have the table setup, but for the life of me I cannot figure out how to display other content on the right (and not have it appear below the table).

Here is my code so far: http://jsfiddle.net/fZJnp/

I would like to have a usable area that takes up the remaining width in the 'content' div.

Here is the css that is applied to the content div and table respectively:

```
#content {
    margin: 0 auto; 
    width:50%;
    height:auto;
    border:solid 1px #003366;
    background-color:#FFF;
    padding:10px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75), 0px -1px 2px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75), 0px -1px 2px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75), 0px -1px 2px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  background:#EEE;
  color:#111;
}
```

Float:left, when applied to the table, seems to let me display information and other elements on the right, however it messes up other elements on the page.

Please let me know what you think, hopefully I explained my problem correctly.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You mean this: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/fZJnp/2/ ?

Comment: [Like this?](http://jsfiddle.net/fZJnp/3/)

Comment: You mean this: http://jsfiddle.net/Jebasuthan/uzB2n/  ?

Comment: Abhitalks: perfect! You should put it in an answer so I can select it or something.

Comment: @WillKavanagh: Thanks. Similar answer has already been posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use two divs, a left and a right. Here is the HTML and CSS I used to make it work. You might want to check out the CSS framework "Bootstrap," released by Twitter. It makes it quite easy to achieve layouts like this using their prewritten stylesheets.

HTML:

```
<body>
      <div id="left">
        <table>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Type</th>
              <th>Destination</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>

            <tr>
              <td>A239</td>
              <td class="Lowsec">Lowsec</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td>A641</td>
              <td class="Highsec">Highsec</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td>A982</td>
              <td class="C6">C6</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td>B041</td>
              <td class="C6">C6</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td>B274</td>
              <td class="Highsec">Highsec</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td>B449</td>
              <td class="Highsec">Highsec</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td>C125</td>
              <td class="C2">C2</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td>C140</td>
              <td class="Lowsec">Lowsec</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td>C247</td>
              <td class="C3">C3</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td>C248</td>
              <td class="Nullsec">Nullsec</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td>C391</td>
              <td class="Lowsec">Lowsec</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td>D364</td>
              <td class="C2">C2</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td>D382</td>
              <td class="C2">C2</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td>D792</td>
              <td class="Highsec">Highsec</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td>D845</td>
              <td class="Highsec">Highsec</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td>E175</td>
              <td class="C4">C4</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td>E545</td>
              <td class="Nullsec">Nullsec</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td>G024</td>
              <td class="C2">C2</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td>H121</td>
              <td class="C1">C1</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td>H296</td>
              <td class="C5">C5</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td>H900</td>
              <td class="C5">C5</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td>I182</td>
              <td class="C2">C2</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td>J244</td>
              <td class="Lowsec">Lowsec</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td>K162</td>
              <td class="Generic Exit">Generic Exit</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td>K329</td>
              <td class="Nullsec">Nullsec</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td>K346</td>
              <td class="Nullsec">Nullsec</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td>L477</td>
              <td class="C3">C3</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td>L614</td>
              <td class="C5">C5</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td>M267</td>
              <td class="C3">C3</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td>M555</td>
              <td class="C5">C5</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td>M609</td>
              <td class="C4">C4</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td>N062</td>
              <td class="C5">C5</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td>N110</td>
              <td class="Highsec">Highsec</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td>N290</td>
              <td class="Lowsec">Lowsec</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td>N432</td>
              <td class="C5">C5</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td>N766</td>
              <td class="C2">C2</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td>N770</td>
              <td class="C5">C5</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td>N968</td>
              <td class="C3">C3</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td>N944</td>
              <td class="Lowsec">Lowsec</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td>O128</td>
              <td class="C4">C4</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td>O477</td>
              <td class="C3">C3</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td>O883</td>
              <td class="C3">C3</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td>P060</td>
              <td class="C1">C1</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td>Q317</td>
              <td class="C1">C1</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td>R051</td>
              <td class="Lowsec">Lowsec</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td>R474</td>
              <td class="C6">C6</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td>R943</td>
              <td class="C2">C2</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td>S047</td>
              <td class="Highsec">Highsec</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td>S199</td>
              <td class="Nullsec">Nullsec</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td>S804</td>
              <td class="C6">C6</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td>T405</td>
              <td class="C4">C4</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td>U210</td>
              <td class="Lowsec">Lowsec</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td>U319</td>
              <td class="C6">C6</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td>U574</td>
              <td class="C6">C6</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td>V283</td>
              <td class="Nullsec">Nullsec</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td>V301</td>
              <td class="C1">C1</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td>V753</td>
              <td class="C6">C6</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td>V911</td>
              <td class="C5">C5</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td>W237</td>
              <td class="C6">C6</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td>X702</td>
              <td class="C3">C3</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td>X877</td>
              <td class="C4">C4</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td>Y683</td>
              <td class="C4">C4</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td>Y709</td>
              <td class="C1">C1</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td>Z060</td>
              <td class="Nullsec">Nullsec</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td>Z142</td>
              <td class="Nullsec">Nullsec</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td>Z457</td>
              <td class="C4">C4</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td>Z647</td>
              <td class="C1">C1</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td>Z971</td>
              <td class="C1">C1</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
          </table></div><div id="right"><p>This is test content</p></div>
        </div>
      </body>
```

CSS:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Myriad Pro Regular';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    src: local('Myriad Pro Regular'), url('MYRIADPRO-REGULAR.woff') format('woff');
    }
    html {
    font-family:'Myriad Pro Regular';
    font-weight:normal;
    background-color:#CCC;
    }
    @font-face {
    font-family: 'Myriad Pro Regular';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    src: local('Myriad Pro Regular'), url('MYRIADPRO-REGULAR.woff') format('woff');
    }
    #left {
    float:left;
    width:50%;
    }
    #right {
    float:right;
    width:50%;
    }
    table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    background:#EEE;
    color:#111;
    }
    th, td {
    border: solid 1px #222;
    padding:5px;
    }
    tr:hover {
    background:#CCC;
    }
    tr.highlight {
    background:yellow;
    }
    td.Highsec, td.C1, td.C2 {
    background-color:#468966;
    }
    td.Lowsec, td.C3, td.C4 {
    background-color:#FFB03B;
    }
    td.Nullsec, td.C5, td.C6 {
    background-color:#8E2800;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/fZJnp/4/)

HTML

```
 <div id="content">
      <div class="leftBar">
<!- your table goes here -->
      </div>
       <div class="rightCnt">
                   test test test tset
       </div>
      <div class="clear"></div>
  </div>
```

CSS

```
.leftBar {
    float: left;
}
.rightCnt {
    margin-left: 150px
}
.clear {
    clear: both
}
```